# Why does MUI Autocomplete example has typescript error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use a MUI Autocomplete component (v5.11) like shown in the [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string | null>(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : 'null'}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I do get two typescript errors (using v4.7.4):

*value*

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
useAutocomplete.d.ts(292, 3): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps<string, undefined, undefined, undefined, "div">'
```

*onChange*

```
Type '(event: any, newValue: string | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: string[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<string>) => void'.
Types of parameters 'newValue' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
useAutocomplete.d.ts(217, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps<string, undefined, undefined, undefined, "div">'
```

I don't see, what is going wrong, as I just used the MUI example without any changes. And of course `value` should be a single string, while the options are an array.

**Update**

Here you can see the configuration, which results in the typescript error: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-rgb-9lot2d?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: this looks fine to me https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e12fd7?file=demo.tsx

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I've added a codesandbox, like I'm using the component. Obviously there is some misconfiguration on my side, but I don't see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `multiple={false}` in the autocomplete

```
  <Autocomplete
    multiple={false}
    value={value}
    onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-banach-wrfps4?file=/src/App.tsx:447-615)

FYI - by default it should come as false but for some reason, have to explicitly set it to false in the code sandbox